# How to read email from gmail using Forntend message id in java via javax mail

Tags: jakarta-mail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

i am usinig gmail contextual gadget to read email in my application, i have used messageid extractor to retriveve message but tat gives me frontend message id now how can i get that email using javax mail with frontend message id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not directly, but you can if you use some java there is a api which can solve your problem and its slow.

you can find it here

https://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/

MY CODE:

```
IMAPFolder folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("[Gmail]/All Mail");

    FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
    fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
    fp.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.X_GM_THRID);
    fp.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.X_GM_MSGID);


    if (folder != null) {
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        folder.fetch(folder.getMessages(), fp);

        GmailMessageIDTerm messageID_term = new GmailMessageIDTerm(Long.parseLong(msgId, 16)+"");
        com.google.code.javax.mail.Message[] messageID_Meassages = folder.search(messageID_term);


        if(messageID_Meassages.length > 0){

            IMAPMessage main_Meassage = (IMAPMessage)messageID_Meassages[0];
            GmailThreadIDTerm thread_term = new GmailThreadIDTerm(main_Meassage.getGoogleMessageId() + "");
            com.google.code.javax.mail.Message[] thread_Messages = folder.search(thread_term);


            for(com.google.code.javax.mail.Message m: thread_Messages){
                IMAPMessage imapMessage = (IMAPMessage)m;
                // here is your every message of current thread 

            }

        }
    }
```